# how do I display the data cleaning results table when I press the data cleaning button?

Tags: python, django

I want to display data cleaning results in the form of tables. but I do not know how to call the function I created in my function page.

```py
def cleaning(a):
    a = data.ffill().bfill()
    return a
```

I expect the output in my HTML page is a table.

Comment: i can't understand you, could you better express what the problem is?

Comment: I just learned Django. I want to display the results of my preprocessing file, which is data cleaning. what I hope for is when I press the data cleaning button, the results will appear on my HTML page. but I am confused on how to display the results in the view page, URL and HTML page.

Comment: I think you should follow Django tutorial, step by step: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I have tried to learn it but I still don't understand